# Removing date part from timestamp in R

Tags: r, date, parsing, lubridate

I have data that looks like this:

```
timestamp                      volume
1  2013-10-29T00:00:00-05:00    650
2  2013-10-29T00:15:00-05:00    778
3  2013-10-29T00:30:00-05:00    683
4  2013-10-29T00:45:00-05:00    723
```

How do I go about removing the date, (this part `2013-10-29T`) so that my column looks like this:

I am having a hard time using `lubridate` . thanks!

```
      timestamp     volume
1  00:00:00-05:00    650
2  00:15:00-05:00    778
3  00:30:00-05:00    683
4  00:45:00-05:00    723
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` ro remove the date part including the `T` by matching characters until the `T` i.e. `.*T` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df1$timestamp <- sub(".*T", "", df1$timestamp)
df1$timestamp
#[1] "00:00:00-05:00" "00:15:00-05:00" "00:30:00-05:00" "00:45:00-05:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `anytime()`

```
R> library(anytime)
R> pt <- anytime(c("2013-10-29T00:00:00-05:00", "2013-10-29T00:15:00-05:00", 
+                  "2013-10-29T00:30:00-05:00", "2013-10-29T00:45:00-05:00"))
R> pt
[1] "2013-10-29 00:00:00 CDT" "2013-10-29 00:15:00 CDT" 
[3] "2013-10-29 00:30:00 CDT" "2013-10-29 00:45:00 CDT"
R> format(pt, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "00:00:00" "00:15:00" "00:30:00" "00:45:00"
R>
```

If you want to add the offset you can do so in the format string:

```
R> format(pt, "%H:%M:%S-05:00")
[1] "00:00:00-05:00" "00:15:00-05:00" "00:30:00-05:00" "00:45:00-05:00"
R>
```

In general, I *stronly* advice against treating dates and times via regular expression.  You are essentially *always* better off with the strong typing of explicit types.  There is a reason they exist.